# Как получить конкретный инкрементный ID?

Tags: javascript, html, button

Всем привет!Я плохо дружу с JavaScript, поэтому искренне надеюсь, что много камней не будет в мою сторону))
У меня появилась проблема, с которой я уже очень долго пытаюсь справиться, но тщетно. На просторах интернета( возможно и этого сайта в том числе) я собрал код, который возращает набор символов(допустим пароль)!
Всё это добро выводится на страницу HTML, где так же есть кнопка, которую я долго искал и тестил. Она единственная, которая заработала =).
Я упростил код, что бы акцентировать внимание на проблеме.

```
    <script> 
//функция обработки нажатия кнопки(работает вроде исправно)

function copyToClipboard() {  
  const str = document.getElementById(num).innerText;
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = str;
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  el.style.position = 'absolute';
  el.style.left = '-9999px';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
}

//функция для генерации пароля

   var  nam;
   var num=0;
   var f=5;
   do{ num++;
  function pass() {
     var words1 = ["aA","bB"];

     var words2 = ["cC","dD"];

     var words3 = ["eE","fF"];

     var words4 = ["gG,"hH"];

     var words5 = ["iI","jJ"];

     var words6 = ["kK","lL"];
     var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words1.length);
     var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words2.length);
     var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words3.length);
     var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words4.length);
     var rand5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words5.length);
     var rand6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words6.length);
     var total = words1[rand1] + "</br>" + words2[rand2] + "</br>" +  words3[rand3] + "</br>" +  words4[rand4] +  "</br>" +  words5[rand5]+ "</br>" +  words6[rand6];
     document.write(num+"."+"<div id="+num+">"+total+"</div>"+"<button onclick='copyToClipboard()' id='k"+num+"'>Скопировать</button><hr>");
    }
     pass();

} while (num<f);


   </script>
```

А теперь по-подробнее. При генерации через рандом,я получаю набор символов, которые хочу сохранить. Для этого и добавлена кнопка. Да, можно всегда обойтись Ctrl+C, но так умеют далеко не все, да и с телефона не очень то удобно, особенно с моего, божеупаси)).
Таким образом, кнопка вызывает функцию, которая нацелена на DIV с id=num. Вроде бы нельзя начинать название div с цифры, но кнопка по-прежнему работает(это конечно легко исправить, но проблема то в другом)

СУТЬ ПРОБЛЕМЫ: **Так вот! На выходе у меня 5 штук наборов букв. Нажимая на любую кнопку Скопировать(их тоже 5!) - она копирует непременно последний набор- что логично, так как num имеет значение 5.
Как мне связать кнопку, например, для 3 набора символов, что бы именно это и было скопировано?**

Я пробовал эксперементировать с самой функцией, добавлял её в разные части кода, не работает. Я искал решения в интернете, а так же копался в справочнике, ничего не нашёл. Как видите, я добавил счётчик кнопке, что вроде бы не обязательно, вроде первой переменной, которую я собирался задействовать, но  это было частью предполагаемого решения.

Мне кажется решение где-то рядом, но моего знания JavaScript не хватает на него. Можете ли вы мне помочь?

Простите за многобуков)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас отпечатка `["gG,` т.е отсутсвует закрывающая кавычка. Во-вторых, чтобы копировать каждую строку по отдельноcти, то вам необходимо передать значение `num`  в `copyToClipboard`

```js
//функция обработки нажатия кнопки(работает вроде исправно)

function copyToClipboard(num) {  
  const str = document.getElementById(num).innerText;
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = str;
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  el.style.position = 'absolute';
  el.style.left = '-9999px';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
}

//функция для генерации пароля

   var  nam;
   var num=0;
   var f=6;
   do{ num++;
  function pass() {
     var words1 = ["aA","bB"];

     var words2 = ["cC","dD"];

     var words3 = ["eE","fF"];

     var words4 = ["gG","hH"];

     var words5 = ["iI","jJ"];

     var words6 = ["kK","lL"];
     var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words1.length);
     var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words2.length);
     var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words3.length);
     var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words4.length);
     var rand5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words5.length);
     var rand6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words6.length);
     var total = words1[rand1] + "</br>" + words2[rand2] + "</br>" +  words3[rand3] + "</br>" +  words4[rand4] +  "</br>" +  words5[rand5]+ "</br>" +  words6[rand6];
     document.write(num+"."+"<div id="+num+">"+total+"</div>"+"<button onclick='copyToClipboard("+num+")' id='k"+num+"'>Скопировать</button><hr>");
    }
     pass();

} while (num<f);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!И ведь я и так пробовал, только саму функцию на счётчик не поставил! А кавычки я пока тут писал - забыл, спасибо!!